# Changing existing database in phprunner application

Tags: php, database

I had developed a web application using phprunner for my school project using MS Access as database and complied the application and hosted on school website.

Now our computer teacher has introduced us to MYSQL database. I want to use my existing code and application but link to a MYSQL database.

However I cannot find an option to change the database.

Comment: depends on the code, did you use PDO ?

Comment: Phprunner is a code generator software where we can select the database type we want to use, there is hardly any manual coding done

Comment: removed numbered list